# Hard time using JS object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strangely structured object which I am trying to convert to an array so that I am able to use filters with ng-repeat.

Here is an example object:

```
var sysData = {
"walkerduct": {
    "id": 0,
    "uri": "walkerduct",
    "name": "Walkerduct",
    "imageS": "img/callcenter.jpg",
    "imageL": "img/callcenter.jpg",
    "copy": "Walkerduct info",
    "relatedSys": [],
    "relatedApp": []
 }
}
```

My controller where I attempt to convert it to an array,

```
inFloorControllers.controller('ApplCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    //alert("OtherCtrl hit");
    $scope.appData = appData;
    $scope.sysData = sysData;
    $scope.title = appData.title;
    $scope.sysArr = [];
    var hasData = true;
    var idx = 0;
    while (hasData) {
        var data = sysData[idx];
        alert("yo");
        if (data) {
            $scope.sysArr.push(data);
            idx++;
        }
        else {
            hasData = false;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.sysArr.length; i++) {
        alert($scope.sysArr[i]);
    }
}
]);
```

And finally my HTML,

```
<div ng-repeat="sys in sysArr | limitTo:3">
    <a href=#/systems/{{sys.uri}}>{{sys.name}}</a>
</div>
```

I'm not seeing what I am doing wrong... it doesn't even hit `if(data)`... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Object.keys` combined with `Array.map`, like this:

```
inFloorControllers.controller('ApplCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.appData = appData;
    $scope.sysData = sysData;
    $scope.title = appData.title;
    $scope.sysArr = Object.keys($scope.sysData).map(function(key){ 
                       return $scope.sysData[key];
                    });
}
]);
```

If you need support for IE8 you will need the [polyfill for the map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).

Comment: Wow. Worked like magic. Now my filter is working. What an excellent solution! Taught me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

That is not a valid json. remove the last comma

```
    {
"walkerduct": {
    "id": 0,
    "uri": "walkerduct",
    "name": "Walkerduct",
    "imageS": "img/callcenter.jpg",
    "imageL": "img/callcenter.jpg",
    "copy": "Walkerduct info",
    "relatedSys": [],
    "relatedApp": []
 }
}
```

Comment: Right, now it is valid. That was there because I truncated my JSON so you wouldn't have to see a ton of JSON. :)

Comment: The OP never actually post any JSON, he posted what the parsed JSON would look like in JavaScript, and did so with a browser specific syntax issue. As the posting was really just pseudo code and no actual JSON was ever posted, there is no way to know if the OP actually has a JSON formatting issue.